# AngularJs - Pass Values from view to controller then to service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I have looked at similar questions, but all don't make sense.
I have we api that i am going to use to login people. They provide the username and password, and then i query the api which returns data that helps me decide whether to login the user or not.
I am trying to figure out how to pass the values from the view to the service, and make the correct url string to query the url. Here is the view

```
<div ng-controller="AppController">
    <input type="text" placeholder="username" ng-model="password" />        
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password" />   
    <input type="submit" value="Sign In" ng-click="login()" />
</div>
```

Then here is the controller

```
app.controller('AppController', function ($scope, AppService) {
    $scope.login = function () {
        $scope.credentials = AppService.getData();
    }        
    $scope.username;
    $scope.password;
});
```

Then the service

```
app.service('AppService', function ($http) {
    this.getData = function () {
        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://www.example.com/api/parent',/*should be http://www.example.com/api/parent?username=username&password=password */
            parameters: {           
            }
        });
    }
});
```

What i need help with is how to append the username and password in the view to create the right query string as in the comment in the service.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While making the call to service from controller, pass the username and password like this AppService.getdata($scope.username, $scope.password). And similarly modify the function definition in AppService to expect username and service as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason you don't want to pass username and password to `getData()`?

Instead `$http` you can use [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) and create more complicated object with custom logic and actions.

Or you can just use $http [params](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage) argument (not parameters) and just pass:

```
parameters{'username': username, 'password': password}
```

Comment: I hadn't thought about passing username and password in the first place. Plus, yes, i changed the argument to params from parameters. It works fine

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the parameters like this:

```
return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://www.example.com/api/parent',/*should be http://www.example.com/api/parent?username=username&password=password */
            parameters: {     
                  username: $scope.username,
                  password: $scope.password
            }
        });
```

Comment: you can't just pass $scope.username and $scope.password. It says $scope is not defined. The best way is to change the getData() function definition to include the params, and then in the controller, u call $scope.credentials = AppService.getData($scope.username, $scope.password);